# Tensor product of the spaces of quaternions and complex numbers

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, ring-theory, quaternions

> Let $ \mathbb{H} $ be the ring of quaternions and make the vector space $A = \mathbb{H} \otimes \mathbb{C}$ into a ring by defining 
>   $$(a \otimes w)(b \otimes z) = (ab \otimes wz) $$
>   for $a,b \in \mathbb{H}$ and $w,z \in \mathbb{C}$
>
> Show that $A \simeq \mathrm{M}_2(\mathbb{C})$
>   the ring of complex $2\times 2$ matrices.

I would normally post my solution attempt but i haven't really gotten anywhere with this problem.

#### Update

Haven't managed to solve this yet, could use some more help.
I admit, i don't quite understand the quaternions or the tensor product.
Does any of this make sense?

$ \mathbb{H} \otimes \mathbb{C}$ = ($ \mathbb{R}1 \oplus \mathbb{R}i \oplus \mathbb{R}j \oplus \mathbb{R}k$) $\otimes$  $\mathbb{C} $ = ($ \mathbb{R}1 \otimes \mathbb{C} $) $\oplus$ ($\mathbb{R}i \otimes \mathbb{C} $) $\oplus$ ($\mathbb{R}j \otimes \mathbb{C} $) $\oplus$ ($\mathbb{R}k \otimes \mathbb{C} $) $\simeq $ $\mathbb{C} \oplus \mathbb{C} \oplus \mathbb{C} \oplus \mathbb{C}$ $ \simeq \mathrm{M}_2(\mathbb{C})$. The last isomorphism is as additive groups by sending (a,b,c,d) to \begin{pmatrix}
        a & b  \\
        c & d  \\
        \end{pmatrix} a,b,c,d $\in \mathbb{C}$

But I don't know how to make it into a ring isomorphism.

Perhaps I could use that $ \mathbb{C} \simeq \begin{pmatrix}
a & -b \\
b & a \\
\end{pmatrix} $ $ a,b \in \mathbb{R}$

Comment: seems like i failed with the code, if someone could help me edit this it'd be great.

Comment: thanks Keenan, that's exactly what i wanted.

Comment: You should mention that you're tensoring over $\Bbb R$.

Comment: yes, missed to write that out.

Comment: @sea turtles: you're assuming that $x$ and $y$ commute.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Ah, thanks. Phew.

Comment: One approach is to use the fact that tensoring preserves presentations; that is, if you write down a presentation of $\mathbb{H}$ as an $\mathbb{R}$-algebra, then the tensor product with $\mathbb{C}$ over $\mathbb{R}$ has the same presentation, but as a $\mathbb{C}$-algebra.

Comment: We haven't really covered that material in class so i am not sure.

Comment: I would expect $1 \otimes 1$ should map to $I \in M_2 ( \mathbb{C})$ and then we just need three matrices which produce the quaternion algebra. Perhaps the Pauli matrices will do. Nope, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pauli_matrices. We'll want $i$ times the Pauli matrices:
$$ i \otimes 1 \mapsto \left[ \begin{array}{cc} 0 & i \\ i & 0 \end{array} \right] $$
$$ j \otimes 1 \mapsto \left[ \begin{array}{cc} 0 & 1 \\ -1 & 0 \end{array} \right] $$
$$ k \otimes 1 \mapsto \left[ \begin{array}{cc} i & 0 \\ 0 & -i \end{array} \right] $$
But, at this point, I merely conjecture these may be useful.

Answer (score 2):

The canonical isomorphism $\Phi:\mathbb{C}\otimes_{\mathbb{R}}\mathbb{H}\to \mathrm{M}_2(\mathbb{C})$ is constructed as follows:

1. $\mathbb{H}\simeq \mathbb{C}^2$ as vector spaces over $\mathbb{C}$. Explicitly, $\gamma: \mathbb{C}^2\to \mathbb{H}$ is $\gamma(z_1,z_2)=z_1 + z_2j$ [Here $i$ is the imaginary unit of $\mathbb{C}$, and $i,j,ij=k$ are the three imaginary units of $\mathbb{H}$]. Given $\mathbb{H}\ni u =z+wj$, we have $$\bar{u}=\bar{z}+\overline{wj}=\bar{z}+\bar{j}\bar{w}=\bar{z}-j\bar{w}=\bar{z}-wj$$
2. We define the *$\mathbb{C}$-algebra* homomorphism $\Phi:\mathbb{C}\otimes_{\mathbb{R}}\mathbb{H}\to \mathrm{M}_2(\mathbb{C})$  via
   $$\Phi(1\otimes u)V=\gamma^{-1}(\gamma(V)\bar{u}), \qquad (z\in \mathbb{C}, u\in \mathbb{H}, V\in \mathbb{C}^2)$$
   Explicitly, if $u=z+w j$, then
   $$
   \phi(u):=\Phi(1\otimes u)=\begin{pmatrix}
   \bar{z} & \bar{w}\\
   -w& z
   \end{pmatrix}
   $$
   To finish, note that $\dim_{\mathbb{C}}\mathbb{C}\otimes_{\mathbb{R}}\mathbb{H}=\dim \mathrm{M}_2(\mathbb{C})=4$, so it suffices to check that $\Phi$ is surjective. Define $I=\phi(i)$, $J=\phi(j)$, $K=\phi(ij)$, then it is easy to check that
   $$\mathrm{M}_2(\mathbb{C})\ni
   \begin{pmatrix}
   a & b\\
   c & d
   \end{pmatrix}=
   \frac{a+d}{2}+\frac{i(a-d)}{2}I+\frac{b-c}{2}J+\frac{i(b+c)}{2}K
   $$
   I want to also mention that the isomorphism $\phi$ is the natural isomorphism $\mathrm{Sp}(1)\to \mathrm{SU}(2)$, where $\mathrm{Sp}(1)$ is the group of unit quaternions.